# Unable to install java in Ubuntu due to broken packages

Tags: java, ubuntu, package

I am trying to install java in my ubuntu software.Every time i am trying to install JRE or JDK it says:

~The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: default-jre-headless (= 1:1.6-43ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre11-1ubuntu1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

and basically anything i try to do is stopped from some broken packages.I tried some cleaning techniques of apt and stuff but nothing helped also.Thank you in advance.

Comment: hello, could you outline the steps you are using to do the installation?

Comment: Java 6 and 7 are no longer supported (and have not been for quite some time). What version of ubuntu are you using, and why are you trying to install Java 6?

Comment: Sounds like a question you should ask on an Ubuntu-related site.

Comment: I am trying to install any java version in my pc and because I couldn't install the new ones I tried some old ones.I found somehow a path and now it says:

The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-5-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

In the past I had installed ecj but it didnt support many things like lists or arrays.Is there a package of these that is fine or should I keep looking?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? And go [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: I am using 16.04

Comment: And now it says :
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `apt-get remove oracle-java11-installer-local` and go to the adoptopenjdk link I gave you. Also, it might be time to consider reinstalling your OS. You seem to have to broken it.

Comment: I figured out some things and I managed to install java 14 oracle.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a conflict between the OpenJDK and Oracle's own DEB distributions for Ubuntu, especially if you've used the webupd8 PPA in the past to install it. I solved it by forcing the override:

`sudo apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" --fix-broken install`

You can also force it directly with dpkg by running

`sudo dpkg --configure --force-overwrite -a`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `apt-get install -f`, which should try to resolve the conflict.

If it does, and there are no more conflicts, then you can try and install `apt-get install default-jre`

Comment: The first one worked well but with the second comand I got again the " you have held broken packages" message

Comment: Did you check https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages ?

Comment: Yeah I ve tried all of these tons of times and nothing worked :(

Comment: does `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` produce any results? if you have held packages, it should list them.. Also if you again run `apt-get install -f` does it still need to fix anything or what is it's exact output?

Comment: The first one doesnt return anything.The second one produces this:Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: You can try the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175624/how-can-i-remove-the-package-oracle-java11-installer-local but please be VERY careful on what you `rm -rf` (remove). This is a way to manually remove `oracle-java11-installer-local` in case it is not needed, or in a case like yours where it is broken (not fully installed)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron!I managed to delete all the java11 folders and install java 14!

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer.